# Transfer big arrays over network in C++ (cpprestsdk)

Tags: c++, opencv, cpprest-sdk

I am using Microsofts "cpprestsdk" as integrated webserver in my application, to communicate with my web based frontend. I want to request a huge "image" from my backend into a canvas element (HTML).

The data is generated with cv2 (Open CV) as a mat object (Basically it's an grayscale image). Currently I am saving the mat as PNG and hand it over to the Frontend. I rather would like to transfer the mat as array or something similar, to draw the image inside my canvas element. That would give me the option to manipulate it inside the frontend.

The mat is created from an 2D short array with 100,000 x 3,000 items.

```
const int width = 100000;
const int height = 3000;

short data[width][height];

cv::Mat test_img(height, width, CV_16S, data);
cv::imwrite("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test.png", test_img);
```

What is the best/ fastest way to transfer this huge data array as response of a web request?

Comment: This is not a valid C++ code.

Comment: You could use RPC or sockets. You can try to use zlib to compress the matrix first. Be aware that test_img(width , height,...) is the wrong order of width and height.

Comment: Micka, thats right :) IN my application the parameters are switched. But I changed the code for this example here, thank you :) I'll take a look how I could use sockets

Comment: I've used civetweb c++ server for such purposes.

Comment: you're asking for "best/fastest"... please show your investigation of the issue and how you would solve this yourself. that would be a basis for discussion and comparison.